# Passando valores de variáveis em ASP.NET e Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma página em asp.net e estou com dificuldades para passar valores de um SELECT do Mysql para variáveis. Não sei por onde começar e agradeceria exemplos de como fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("caminho da base de dados");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string fu = "SELECT* FROM Tb_Banco where id=2";
            cmd.CommandText = fu;
            MySqlDataReader R;
            R = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            R.Read();

            string Conta_Banco = R["Conta"].ToString();
            string Nome_Banco = R["Banco"].ToString();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, isso respondeu minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

esta pergunta é quase um How To, então lá vai um link para se baseares, como não temos como saber a profundidade do seu conhecimento, deixo este how to básico:

[Conectando C# ao MySQL](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/13681/mysql/conectando-c-ao-mysql?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Sugiro também que procure aprender Entity Framework!

Comment: Maurício, eu desenvolvia em php, porém, fiquei um tempo sem desenvolver e agora para fazer um sistema para o meu trabalho sinto a necessidade de usar o asp.net. Obrigado pelo link.

Comment: Disponha @ThiagoPires ! Sou desenvolvedor a bastante tempo de .NET e continuo aprendendo coisas até hoje! Sempre podemos ajudar quem precisa e sempre aprendemos com os outros! Bom aprendizado e bem vindo ao mundo .NET!

Se estás começando sugiro que aprenda MVC .NET é muito bom, juntamente com LINQ to Entities!